# Como controlar eventos de elementos HTML inseridos posteriormente dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, dinâmico

Eu gerei um cartão de profissionais HTML com JavaScript. A lista é populada após clicar na categoria:

```
var professionalsCards = '';
$.each(professionalsData, function(i, item)
{
    professionalsCards += '<div class="col-md-3 professional_list_card">';
    professionalsCards += '<a href="#" onclick="showProfessionalDetails()">';
    professionalsCards += '<div class = "panel panel-default professional_list_panel">';
    professionalsCards += '<img src="'+websiteTPL+'images/user-without-avatar-400x400.jpg" height="75px" width="75px" alt="..." class="img-circle center-block" />';
    professionalsCards += '<h4 class="text-center">'+item.fullname+'</h4>';
    professionalsCards += '<input type="hidden" id="professional_uuid" name="professional_uuid" value="teste" />';
    professionalsCards += '</div></a></div>';
});

$("div#professionals_list").html(professionalsCards);
```

Quando eu populo diretamente no HTML funciona normal:

```
$(".professional_list_card").click(function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var professional_uuid = jQuery(this).find("input:hidden");
    alert(professional_uuid.val());
});
```

Mas quando eu insiro os elementos HTML dinamicamente a função click não funciona.
Então, eu tentei a função onclick, não funciona também:

```
function showProfessionalDetails()
{
    var professional_uuid = jQuery(this).find("input:hidden");
    alert(professional_uuid.val());
}
```

*Tentei também colocar on como sugerido no comentário, também não funciona:

```
$("#professionals_list").on("click", "#professional_list_card").click(function(event)
    {
        //event.preventDefault();
        //var professional_uuid = jQuery(this).find("input:hidden");
        //alert(professional_uuid.val());
        alert('Teste');
    });
```

Também tentei:

```
$(document).on("click", "#professional_list_card", function()
    {
        //event.preventDefault();
        //var professional_uuid = jQuery(this).find("input:hidden");
        //alert(professional_uuid.val());
        alert('Teste');
    });
```

Nos 2 Casos acima da o erro: **HierarchyRequestError**

Como eu posso controlar o HTML inserido dinamicamente com JavaScript? O Evento click e outros eventos?

**RESOLVIDO POR OSMOSE NOVAMENTE!!!**

Coloquei:

```
$('div#professionals_list').append(professionalsCards);
```

No Lugar de:

```
$("div#professionals_list").html(professionalsCards);
```

E Resolveu!

*"GRATO"*

Obrigado!

Comment: Conforme o link marcado, use o método `.on`: `$(document).on("click", seletor, function(){...`

Comment: eu fiz isso, não funciona também!

Comment: HierarchyRequestError

Comment: Esse `professional_list_card` é uma classe. Deveria usar um ponto `.` antes e não `#`, desta forma: `$(document).on("click", ".professional_list_card", function(){...`

Comment: desculpe, é que colei do código anterior.. mas já tem id com ele e da o erro de hierarquia também! resolvi usando      $('div#professionals_list').append(professionalsCards); no lugar de $("div#professionals_list").html(professionalsCards); GRATO!

Comment: Entendi. Então o problema era com o `append` também e não com os eventos apenas.

Comment: Pelo jeito sim. Grato pelas dicas!